# How to handle Hibernate SessionFactory in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am learner and and Does anyone know how to get a handle the Hibernate Session Factory that is created by Spring Boot? i seen number of solutions and i implement below code but i am getting exception when hit service

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
```

### application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

### configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootCurd1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootCurd1Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf) {
        return hemf.getSessionFactory();
    }

}
```

### dao

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * getListOfStates
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public List<?> getListOfStates(int userId) {

        String hql = "FROM states s WHERE " + "s.userid = :userId";
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("userId", userId);
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
        return query.list();

    }

}
```

Comment: Why? Just use JPA, the `EntityManager` instead of `SessionFactory` and `Session`... Unless you really need a `Session` you can always do `EntityManager.unwrap(Session.class)` to get the underlying session. But currently in your code, there is nothing that warrants the use of plain Hibernate.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use plain hibernate but use JPA as the API, unless you really need specific Hibernate specific features (which looking at your code you don't need).

So rewrite your code to use an `EntityManager` instead:

```
Repository
public class EmployeeDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    /**
     * getListOfStates
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public List<State> getListOfStates(int userId) {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM states s WHERE s.userid = :userId", State.class)
            .setParameter("userId", userId)
            .getResultList();

    }
}
```

Now if you really need access to the `Session` use `EntityManager.unwrap(Session.class)` to obtain it.

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    /**
     * getListOfStates
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public List<?> getListOfStates(int userId) {

        String hql = "FROM states s WHERE " + "s.userid = :userId";
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("userId", userId);
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
        return query.list();

    }
}
```

However as stated you should really prefer JPA over the plain API of Hibernate.

**NOTE:** You can now also remove the `@Bean` method that produces a `SessionFactory`.

Comment: Right and clean explanation. Hat's off

Comment: can i remove spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
 in application.properties?

Comment: You should be able to do that when using this approach.